# select day and special date load by ajax to set in gldatepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using gldatepicker.I want to load some settings from database by ajax for gldatepicker such as day of week,special date etc.Now i have following js code for this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadAllSettings();
});
var loadAllSettings = function () {
    startDate = '';
    endDate = '';
    selectDay = '';
    offdays = '';

    $.ajax({
        url: "bs_client_function.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            action: 'getDateRange'
        },
        success: function (html) {
            // alert(html.start);
            startDate = Date.parse(html.start);
            endDate = Date.parse(html.end);
        }

    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "bs_client_function.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            action: 'getOffdays'
        },
        success: function (html) {
            i = 0;
            offdays = '[';
            while (i < html.length) {
                offdays = offdays + {
                    date: new Date(html[i]),
                    repeatYear: false,
                    cssClass: 'noday'
                };
                i = i + 1;
            }
            offdays = offdays + ']';
        }

    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "bs_client_function.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            action: 'getDays'
        },
        success: function (html) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(html);
            // alert("[" + data + "]");
            selectDay = '[' + data + ']';
            // alert(selectDay);
           showCalender(startDate, endDate, selectDay, offdays);
        }

    });
    alert(selectDay);
    console.log('selectDay' + selectDay);

};
```

I have checked all data is correctlly formated as gldatepicker recommanded.In my show calender
function:

```
var showCalender = function (startDate, endDate, selectDay, offdays) {
    var dd = $('#mydate').glDatePicker({
        showAlways: true,
        allowMonthSelect: true,
        allowYearSelect: false,
        prevArrow: '\u25c4',
        nextArrow: '\u25ba',
        cssName: 'darkneon',
        selectableDOW: selectDay,
        dowOffset: 0,
        selectedDate: new Date(),
        selectableDateRange: [{
            from: new Date(startDate),
            to: new Date(endDate)
        }, ],
        specialDates: offdays
    });
};
```

Now only  stardate and enddate rightly working.selectDay,offdays are not working. i print selectDay in the console i got this: [1,2,3] but it not woking.What i am missing or what should be right way to do it. 
    **Thanks in advance...**

Comment: with a tiny bit of extra work on your end you could create a fiddle that loads your code and the library you're using.  Then those that aren't familiar with gldatepicker library specifically could probably help

Comment: but i do notice that you have synchronous code that relies upon an AJAX (asynchronous code) completing first.  You should be using a promise model or a callback model and make the call to `showCalendar` dependent upon the asynch methods completing

Comment: thanks– gillyspy for quick reply.Would you please give me some references guide to make it works??

Comment: Hi gillyspy ,I've edit my question. now i'm calling showcalender inside ajax success.it also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you are getting your data for fill the glDatePicker.
You have 3 ajax calls, these calls are by default asynchronous, you execute your showCalender function in the last success function, but you have no sureness that the preceding calls are completed.

You can make your ajax calls synchronous by setting the `async` parameter to `false` see the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8,
>   the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you
>   must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the
>   corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the
>   deprecated jqXHR.success().

or you can chain them in every success callbacks, but your code will be difficult to mantain or you can use this plugin to manager multiple ajax calls http://docs.jquery.com/AjaxQueue

It works well with local data, see: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/V59E7/

Pay attention only at the object that `specialDates` option needs:

```
   specialDates: [{
       date: new Date(0, 8, 5),
       data: {
           message: 'Happy Birthday!'
       },
       repeatYear: true,
       cssClass: 'special-bday'
   }, {
       date: new Date(2013, 0, 8),
       data: {
           message: 'Meeting every day 8 of the month'
       },
       repeatMonth: true
   }]
```

Comment: Hi Edward thanks for awesome reply.I need to check it.If it works then i will mark your answer.Thanks again.

Comment: Regarding specialDates i need to run a loop through all .Its not static.And i saw your fiddle code.In my code local data is working fine.Is there any problems in formatting data which all i getting from ajax???

Comment: There are no problem, you must only set locally or return from your ajax call an array ob object formatted as specialDates needs see: http://jsfiddle.net/V59E7/1/

Comment: how should i return array object??would you please give me an example??

Comment: How are you returning now your offdays variabile from the ajax call getOffdays?

Comment: From ajax i got an array(name html) like this: html('0'=>'2013-x-x','1'=>'2013-5-6','2'=>'2013-8-5'); then i want to format as gldatepicker want in the offdays var.and finally i want use offdays var in gldatepicker.

Comment: Hi Edward It works.I just added async to false in all ajax request and it works fine.you are right it was synchronization problems. Thanks again ..